# correct way of creating a executable jar

Tags: java, jar

I have the following directory structure.

```
src|
   |pack|
        |Test.java
data|
    |data.txt

classes|
       |pack|
            |Test.class
manifest.txt
```

It compiled and ran fine.

```
\project>javac -d classes src\pack\Test.java
\project>java -cp classes pack.Test
```

Contents of Test.java

```
package pack;
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data\\data.txt"));
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            br.close();
        }catch(IOException e){System.out.println("FileNotFound");}
    }
}
```

Contents of manifest.txt

```
Main-Class: pack.Test
```

How to create the jar file? and from where should I execute it?

Comment: you should look at using maven, and it's assembly plugin.

Comment: yes. I have heard about it. But how shall I proceed the plain way?

Comment: Eclipse? It has something like packaging them into a single jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manually create a jar then take a look at the jar command. Something like this, in your case:

```
jar -cvfm name.jar manifest.txt -C classes .
```

However, please note that the name of the manifest file should be MANIFEST.MF.

Also, I suggest you start learning a build tool like ant or maven or gradle such as you can do this automatically.

Comment: I renamed manifest.txt to manifest.mf. then `jar -cvfm test.jar manifest.mf -C classes . data` and it worked.

Comment: The standard name is MANIFEST.MF (in upper case). Not sure about other names, it may work.